# Dojo widget not rendered correctly, when placed in inactive accordion container

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a web application using the ArcGIS JS API with a bunch of custom widgets.
If I place an `esri/dijit/editing/TemplatePicker` inside a ContentPane inside an Accordion container tab, which is inactive, when the page loads, the template picker does not render correctly.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/n9jwtgko/1/)
2. Switch to the first accordion pane. The widget is just a border with no content
3. Now change the selected pane by settings `selected="true"`

   ```
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Heeh, this is a content pane" selected="true">
       <div id="templatePickerDiv"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. remove `selected="true"` from the second container
5. refresh the fiddle

The widget now loads up correctly.

What exactly is happening here and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem really seems to be either the templatepicker or the Accordion. If I remove either from the application it works just fine, so my plan was to make sure, the parser runs only after everything has finished - including events like `layers-add-result`.

Since my application is already modularized into a mapLoader, widgets, services and so on, I decided to refactor the mapLoader into a deferred object.

```
define([/*...*/, function(){
    var init = function() {
       return $.when(function(){
                 //bootstrap map
                 //bootstrap widgets
                 //create new Deferred object
                 var dfd = $.Deferred();
                 function initEditing() {
                    /*hook up the rest*/
                    //resolve promise once the templatepicker is up and running
                    dfd.resolve();
                 }
                 //return promise
                 return dfd.promise();
              })
    };
    return {init: init}
}])
```

Now with that in place I can just go ahead in my startup file and call:

```
define([
    "dojo/parser",
    "app/components/mapLoader.public",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (parser, MapLoader
) {
     //entry point into the application
     //authentication, configuration etc. omitted

     MapLoader.init().done(function () {
        parser.parse();
     });
});
```

This is the only way I found so far to make sure every widget is loaded, before the parser actually runs and does its black magic. Of Ccourse now I just need to clean everything up and replace jQuerys defferred object with the dojo implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when I use "Dojo" I change things and work, but I do not know why. It works in this way. The "parse.parse ()" part is running after the end of the code.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9jwtgko/45/)

```
parser.parse();
```

Comment: While this might work, it does not gurantee to work, because you might need to wait for events to happen. I found a consistent solution to my problem and will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Upon close look at the HTML file (with autoSelect=true and without), I can see that without autoselect=true, your grid not getting the right width. This is the HTML version of the grid. If you see element 'dojoxGridHeader', width is 0px but where as with autoselect=true, it would become 'width=178px'. So check your CSS also you can also grid.startup() when that accord container is loaded. Hope it helps.

```
<div hidefocus="hidefocus" role="grid" dojoattachevent="onmouseout:_mouseOut" tabindex="0" class="dojoxGrid grid" id="dojox_grid_DataGrid_0" align="left" widgetid="dojox_grid_DataGrid_0" aria-readonly="true" style="height: auto; width: 1px; user-select: none;">
    <div class="dojoxGridMasterHeader" dojoattachpoint="viewsHeaderNode" role="presentation" style="display: block; height: 0px;"><div class="dojoxGridHeader" dojoattachpoint="headerNode" role="presentation" style="display: none; width: 0px; left: 1px; top: 0px;">
        <div dojoattachpoint="headerNodeContainer" style="width:9000em" role="presentation">
            <div dojoattachpoint="headerContentNode" role="row"><table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="dojox_grid_DataGrid_0Hdr0" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="0" style="width:6em;"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">cell0</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="dojox_grid_DataGrid_0Hdr1" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="1" style="width:6em;"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">cell1</div></th></tr><tr><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="dojox_grid_DataGrid_0Hdr2" colspan="2" class="dojoxGridCell " idx="2" style=""><div class="dojoxGridSortNode">groupName</div></th></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the width, but the functionality of the widget itself and the reason for it. I can always tweak the styling later on.

Comment: well if you don't have the right width set, then the grid won't display. It sets the right width when you make that accord container as selected by setting autoSelect=true